# Where should you run intensive reports on MongoDB from

Tags: mongodb, reporting

We have a production system that uses MongoDB as it's data storage and writes a lot of the actions it completes there.

I'd like to run some reports to see what is going on and if this was a MSSQL DB I'd have a replicated server setup so I didn't cause any locks that might effect the live system.

Is this necessary in MongoDB?

I was considering adding a Hidden server that could be used to run queries from, but I haven't investigated that in any detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously any queries you run for reporting are going to add load to the server.  Depending on what types of queries your reports are running will affect how big of an impact this will have.  It is definitely possible to set up a dedicated secondary for the sole purpose of reporting.  You could then make a direct connection to that secondary and do slaveOk queries to run your reports.  This page has information on how to set up a hidden replica set member: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Configuration#ReplicaSetConfiguration-Memberoptions.

Comment: For the Hidden member. Do you know why it says "It is rare to use this option." Reporting is very common, and if this is a suggested way to do it, why is it rare?

Comment: Most people just run this kind of stuff off of a normal secondary, making the secondary hidden is rarer, though there are still a decent number of people doing so. It really depends on how expensive the operations you're running for reporting are and how much load your secondaries are under. If you don't do secondary reads, or if you do but load on the secondary is light, or if the queries being used for reporting are lightweight, then you don't need a hidden secondary dedicated to reporting and can reuse your standard secondary.